# ERROR in ***.service.ts(1,21): error TS2305: Module '"***@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Response'

Tags: angular

> ERROR in src/app/shared/services/users.service.ts(1,21): error TS2305:
>   Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/home-money/node_module
>   s/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Response'.

Can't resolve the problem

```js
import {HttpClient, Response} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {User} from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users?email=${email}`)
            .map((response: Response) => response)
            .map((user: User[]) => user[0] ? user[0] : undefined);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know below answer is working for you

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda I think your answer is helped. Don't see anymore issue. Thank you

Comment: Then please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda ah sorry, done

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda after fixes Response -> HttpResponse
i got this "ERROR in src/app/shared/services/users.service.ts(13,23): error TS2314: Generic type 'HttpResponse<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is in **`import {HttpClient, Response} from '@angular/common/http';`**
There is no exported member as Response in **`@angular/common/http`**. It should be **`HttpResponse`**.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

    getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users?email=${email}`)
            .map((response: HttpResponse) => response)
            .map((user: User[]) => user[0] ? user[0] : undefined);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong is should be

```
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
```

And also no need for this

```
.map((response: HttpResponse) => response)
```

I'm not seeing you do anything to modify the response data